# Add and update dynamic option for a select option - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code below adds a dynamic option to select options from the textbox values, but it is appending the values the number of times the user clicks the select input, I have tried the click once `{once : true}` option on the function which does not solve my problem completely.

What I think would work is to add the dynamic option to the select options without the `appendTo()` so it only takes and updates the dynamic option in accordance with the value in the textbox.

How can I go about that, please?

```
let selectAnswer = document.getElementById('answer-'+ index +'');
    selectAnswer.addEventListener("click", function() {

        var optionAValue = $question.find('#optionA-'+ index + '').val()
        var optionBValue = $question.find('#optionB-'+ index + '').val()
        var optionCValue = $question.find('#optionC-'+ index + '').val()
        var optionDValue = $question.find('#optionD-'+ index + '').val()

        $('<option>').val(optionAValue).text(optionAValue).appendTo('#answer-'+ index +'');
        $('<option>').val(optionBValue).text(optionBValue).appendTo('#answer-'+ index +'');
        $('<option>').val(optionCValue).text(optionCValue).appendTo('#answer-'+ index +'');
        $('<option>').val(optionDValue).text(optionDValue).appendTo('#answer-'+ index +'');

        
    });
```

Comment: Post HTML and JS/jQ as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The HTML in your question was missing. I made up some stuff to demonstrate how you can do the task in a much lighter, more parametric way:

```js
const $id = id => document.getElementById(id); // helper function 
document.body.onclick = (ev, index) => { // delegated click event handler
  // steps into action only for the ID pattern: /answer-(\d+)/
  if (index = ((ev.target.id ?? "").match(/answer-(\d+)/) ?? [])[1]) {
    ev.target.innerHTML = "ABCD".split("").map(c => { // for options A,B,C and D:
      const id = `option${c}-${index}`; 
      return `<option id="${id}">${($id(id)??{}).value??""}</option>`;
    }).join("\n"); // create new innerHTML for select element: ev.target
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Questions</h2>

question 1:<br>
<input id="optionA-1" type="text" value="first option"><br>
<input id="optionB-1" type="text" value="a second option"><br>
<input id="optionC-1" type="text" value="and a third one"><br>
<input id="optionD-1" type="text" value="this is the fourth and last option.">

<h2>Select</h2>
<select id="answer-1"></select> Answers 1<br>
<select id="answer-2"></select> Answers 2<br>
<select id="answer-3"></select> Answers 3<br>
<select id="answer-4"></select> Answers 4<br>
```

So far only the first select box will get updated answers from the above input fields, as the input fields for the other question are still missing.

I also took the liberty of writing a vanilla JavaScript solution. You *did* use some jQuery expressions in your code but you did not really make use of its power so I decided to go without it.

The expression `($id(id)??{}).value??""` does the following:

- find the element with id `id`,
- if it doesn't exist, return `{}` (an empty object) instead,
- get its property `.value` and if that isn't found, return an empty string instead.

**UPDATE**

OK, so here is the whole thing with jQuery support:

```js
function replaceOpts(index) {
  // replace Options for select:
  $("#answer-" + index).html($(`input.question${index}`).map((i, c) =>
    `<option>${c.value??""}</option>`).get().join("\n"));
}
$("body").on("input", "input[class^=question]", function() { // delegated click event handler
  // only act, if id matches /question(\d+)/ 
  replaceOpts(((this.className ?? "").match(/question(\d+)/) ?? [])[1]);
})
$("select").each(function(){replaceOpts(this.id.replace(/^.*-/,""));})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Questions</h2>

question 1:<br>
<input class="question1" type="text" value="first option"><br>
<input class="question1" type="text" value="a second option"><br>
<input class="question1" type="text" value="and a third one"><br>
<input class="question1" type="text" value="this is the fourth and last option."><br><br> question 3:<br>
<input class="question3" type="text" value="numero uno"><br>
<input class="question3" type="text" value="dos"><br>
<input class="question3" type="text" value="y tres."><br>


<h2>Select</h2>
<select id="answer-1"></select> Answers 1<br>
<select id="answer-2"></select> Answers 2<br>
<select id="answer-3"></select> Answers 3<br>
<select id="answer-4"></select> Answers 4<br>
```

In this jQuery rewrite I also let go of the `id`s in the question-`inputs`. Instead I worked with `class="question..."`. This makes it easier to process questions with a variable number of answer-options. While writing write less code at the same time!

The second approach could of course also be done without jQuery.

Comment: This is exactly what I want, but I don't understand some parts of the code for me to adapt it to my code.

Comment: Can you do this solution in jquery?

Comment: The select button does not select a value, it is stuck at "first option"

Comment: It does show me all the options on my browser (currently a smartphone Chrome).

Comment: Yes, it does show all the options but stuck at the "first option" whenever I select the other options.

Comment: After testing it on my PCs Chrome I got the same behaviour as you. Please try my changed snippet, as I now update the options every time an input field is changed. This removes the conflicht I had before.